# Utility functions in a namespace or in a class?

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

Until now if I needed some commonly used utility functions I moved them into a utility class. In a way like this:

```
#pragma once

class QDate;
class QDateEdit;
class QDialog;
class QWidget;

class GuiUtils final
{
public:
    static void moveDialog( QDialog* aDialog, const int aMargin = 4 );
    static void setMainWidget( QWidget* aParent, QWidget* aChild, const int aMargin = 0 );

    static void setValueBlocked( QDateEdit* aDateEdit, const QDate& aDate );

private:
    GuiUtils();
};

class DateUtils final
{
public:
    static QDate today();
    static QDate yesterday();
    static QDate firstDayOfWeek();
    static QDate firstDayOfMonth();
    static QDate firstDayOfQuarter();
    static QDate firstDayOfYear();

    static int quarter( const QDate& aDate );
    static int quarter( const int aMonth );

private:
    DateUtils();
};
```

But I know that there is an other option for this. I could move all my functions into a namespaces. In a way like this:

```
#pragma once

class QDate;
class QDateEdit;
class QDialog;
class QWidget;

namespace gui_utils
{
    void moveDialog( QDialog* aDialog, const int aMargin = 4 );
    void setMainWidget( QWidget* aParent, QWidget* aChild, const int aMargin = 0 );

    void setValueBlocked( QDateEdit* aDateEdit, const QDate& aDate );
};

namespace date_utils
{
    QDate today();
    QDate yesterday();
    QDate firstDayOfWeek();
    QDate firstDayOfMonth();
    QDate firstDayOfQuarter();
    QDate firstDayOfYear();

    int quarter( const QDate& aDate );
    int quarter( const int aMonth );
};
```

For me it seems a better solution for creating a utility class than a namespace. I see that I need to type more, but if I need to define a new namespace for all utility function group it would look a bit extreme for me. I don't usually create new namespaces but classes every time so that's why I use the first option.

But now I would like to know that:

- is there any advantage of using a namespace for this purpose ?
- does it have a better performane of using namespaces for this purpose ?
- does it better fits in the concepts of `C++` ?
- is there any other reason for using namespaces for this ?

I would like to know your opinions but I need explanations as well. I don't want to rewrite my existing codes and writing the new ones with a different style "just because". I need some language/performance based or any other kind of explanation why to use it in one or in another way.

Thanks for help.

Comment: A class with only static member functions is really no different from a namespace, except you have to make sure that the class can't be instantiated. Use a namespace. If, on the other hand, there needs to be some common state shared between the functions, it makes more sense to turn it into a normal class that you instantiate.

Comment: There won't be any performance difference if you are not instancing the class. The only difference is that you can not do `using class utils;`.

Comment: Another advantage of namespaces is that you can write `using namespace` and refer to functions without writing namespace name each time. Also using functions makes it clear that they are stateless (this is not guaranteed but presumed by default). On the contrary, using static class functions is a reason to believe that there is some stored state in this class.

Comment: I usually write down the name of the namespace because we use a lot of SDKs and without the names of namespace there would be conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in your case, using a namespace is a better choice for a variety of reasons.

For example:

1. It appears that your functions do not share data.
2. Namespaces enable ADL (Argument Dependent name Lookup).

See any of several style guides.   Here is a clip from [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Nonmember,_Static_Member,_and_Global_Functions):

***Nonmember, Static Member, and Global Functions
Prefer placing nonmember functions in a namespace;...
Rather than creating classes only to group static member functions which do not share static data, use namespaces instead. ***